# Copy-Paste duplicate flag declined for language tag

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, declined-flags

The body of [Abstract factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513086/) is copy/pasted from [Why do we need Abstract factory design pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280170). The flag I raised to merge these threads was declined because the copy adds `C#` to its title and tags.

Should I conclude that adding a language tag to any language-agnostic question results in a brand new question, by SO standards?

Secondly, note that the copy was not originally a copy, but was edited by the author a month later. Would it be appropriate to roll back that latest edit? The original content wasn't really any better than the copied content, but at least it wasn't copied.

While the accepted answer to the copied question does include `C#` syntax in its example, it is more pseudo-code than working functionality. The answer would be equally applicable (and equally helpful) as an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I have rolled back the last edit of [Why use Abstract factory pattern in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10513086/660921) (now: Abstract factory pattern).

Copy/pasting other people's posts wholesale without any attribution is called plagiarism and is never acceptable in any shape or form. Questions are no exception.

In addition, all of the actual answers were posted with the *old* content as the question. One of the answers even quotes that. So ignoring the plagiarism, the new version is actually more confusing than anything else since the answers no longer match up.

It's also a question that's far too broad and have voted to close it.